# MongoDB sharded cluster using docker with persistent storage issue

Tags: mongodb, docker, cluster-computing, mount

I have been able to create a sharded cluster using docker which has 3 shards and each shard is a replica set, and each member of the replica set has persistent storage which I have tested and works.

The issue is, when I stop and delete the docker containers and then bring them up again to use the same persistent storage the shards do not attach to the cluster, after googling I believe this is because they have already been attached to a cluster previously.

Output of sh.status( { verbose : 1 } ) shows no shards

Output of sh.addShard("a/mongo-shard-a0:27017") shows:

```
"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.system.version index: _id_ dup key: { : \"shardIdentity\" }"
```

I naively presumed that when the docker containers came back and pointed towards the same data directory the cluster would be as it was before deleting the containers.

Any help with this one is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was setting up persistent storage to the /data/db directory for the configsvr's where in actual fact I need to mount the persistent storage within the docker file to the /data/configdb directory.